# Can I use Npgsql Data Provider in my .NET 4.0 project?

Tags: postgresql, .net-4.0, npgsql

I have an MVC project that I would like to write in .NET 4.0

Is it possible to use Npgsql (which currently supports .net 3.5 ) if I will use it through Entity Framework, and I will limit myself to features of EF contained within 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npgsql now supports .net 4.0 :D so question is no longer valid.